# web hosts with scala installed

Tags: scala, content-management-system, hosting, blogs

I want to develop a CMS and blog engine based on scala as a project. My current web host does not have scala installed. Does anybody know of a webhost (it doesn't have to be free but relatively basic - this will be low traffic and low storage volume) that runs scala?

Comment: CloudBees also support Scala, it also has free plans -- limited resource, but works fine for development and testing.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to have scala installed. All you need is a JVM. You'll need to include the scala libraries in your solution (war) though.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a good tutorial on setting up a scala system on a webhost with Java?

Comment: Not a link, but I'd recommend looking into Jetty.